# Problems creating child processes with fork and getting multiple unwanted processes

Tags: c, fork

I working with creating several child processes and passing data around using message queues.  I've cut out most of the detail of my code because it's a bit too big to post homework online and I've narrowed down the bug to have something to do with how I'm creating and dealing with child processes.

The basics of how the program work are:

1. read from stdin
2. fork a child process (type 1) to do stuff with the data
3. send that data to X number of child processes of type 2 via message queue
4. they do stuff with the data and pass it via message queue to the print_queue function
5. The type2 processes wait until their message queue is empty (read by print_queue) before they hit exit(0)

Every thing in the program that I cut out works and is tested.  Message passing is working, reading and calculating stuff from stdin is working.  The problem comes up when I am printing the data back out.  The results depend on the size of the data set and how I'm getting the data back.  If I print to the terminal everything works out just fine. If I redirect the output to a file I get the following results (remember that I printf "Starting program" at the top of main):

```
** valid data
.
. x100k more lines of valid data
.
.
** valid data
** vali Starting Program
Starting Program
```

Note that it looks like the program is restarting its self twice at the end.  The program runs just fine for smaller data sets and even a very large data set when printing to the screen.  Another even stranger bug is when I comment out the "Starting Program" printf.  That for some reason always causes the program to segfault.

Here is the condensed version of the source code:

```
    /*
      fork a process, child process type 1
    */
    void Process1(){

      switch(fork()){
        case 0:

         // Read some stuff from stdin

         // Pass data to other child processes through msgsnd

        //  wait until message queue is empty

         // close message queue, to tell child processes (type 2)
       //   that there is no more data

         break;
        case -1:
          perror("error fork\n");
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

    }


    /*
      fork a process of type 2
    */
    void process2( ){

      switch(fork()){
        case 0:

         //   Create a child process type-2

         //   Do stuff with this data

        //    send data back to print_queues function 
         //   to do stuff with and display the results

        //    exit to get out and avoid going back to main

          exit(0);

        case -1:
          perror("error fork\n");
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }


    void print_queues(){

       //   This just prints data sent to it from process2 message queues
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

     // get a value num from argv, this is the 
    // number of instances of process2 that we will create

      while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "n:")) != -1)
      {
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'n':
          if(atoi(optarg) < 0 || atoi(optarg) > 50){
            printf("invalid No \n");
            num = 1;
          }
          else{
            num = atoi(optarg);
          }
          // create memory for key and queue arrays
          Keys = malloc(sizeof(key_t)*num);
          queues = malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
          fflush(stdout);
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
      }

      printf("Starting program\n");

      // create num version of child2
      for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        process2();
      }

      // create process1
      process1(); 

     // wait for process 1 to finish
      wait(NULL);

    // print the output from the message queues
      print_queues();

    // wait for num versions of process2 to finish
      for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        wait(NULL);
      }

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: In your debugger, put a breakpoint at the forks and then look at the stack trace when you get there.

Comment: ahh that gave me more questions than answers.  It segfaults way before the fork when I run gdb but no segfault when it runs normally.

Comment: You probably have some memory corruption occuring then (e.g. writing past the bounds of malloc'd area)

Comment: Something with malloc is a bit weird.  One of my arrays is not allocated when I run with gdb but is fine normally.

Comment: Step through the code where it is supposed to be allocating that array. Are you checking all your `*alloc` calls that they don't return `NULL` ?

Comment: I have an assert right after calls.

Comment: Perhaps you overflow a buffer somewhere that writes over that pointer.

Comment: Not even sure how to debug that.  I added a printf(getpid()) at the spot where if prints "Starting Program" and it's the same pid each time.  Not sure if that helps.  I would have expected them to come from different processes.